# Custom image for Facebook share button

Tags: javascript, html, css, facebook

I've been searching around the internet for a while now and am unable to find anything that works. I want to use my own custom image for the share button but whenever I try to surround the image the share button disappears. Sorry for lack of information because I'm new to the Facebook SDK. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Current code that I have:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"><img src="Images/Icons/facebook.png" class="link"></div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a bit of the code you created so far?

Comment: I found that very difficult too, so I normally use Addthis, so that can easily change the the look of the button.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This code works fine for me:

```
<!-- facebook -->
<img src="[YOUR_FACEBOOK_PIC]" alt="Share on Facebook" onclick="window.open('https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent('[YOUR_PAGE_URL]'),'facebook-share-dialog','width=626,height=436'); return false;">

<!-- twitter -->
<img src="[YOUR_TWITTER_PIC]" alt="Share on Twitter" onclick="javascript:window.open('https://twitter.com/share?text=[SOME_TEXT_TO_PREPOLUTATE_TWEET]&amp;url=[YOUR_PAGE_URL]','Twitter-dialog','width=626,height=436'); return false;">

<!-- google+ -->
<img src="[YOUR_GOOGLE_PIC]" alt="Share on Google Plus" onclick="window.open('https://plus.google.com/share?url=[YOUR_PAGE_URL]','Google-dialog','width=626,height=436'); return false;">
```

Just replace the text between brackets, and don't forget to "url encode" all the text that goes in the url to avoid issues.

And it doesn't need the SDK for any of them.

---

Here are references to the official documentation for each of them:

- [Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) (you can see it under the [URL redirection](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog#redirect) section)
- [Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button/parameters#web-intent-example) (you could also use https://twitter.com/intent/tweet as described [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/tweet-button))
- [Google+](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#share-link) (under Share Link section)

Comment: Is there a way to do this for other social networks such as Twitter and Google+?

Comment: Yes. I have this code on a Web page, let me find it and copy it here

Comment: Where is the documentation for this?. I feel like this is a secret. This is such an easier way of going about than what I was planning on doing. I feel like this is too good to be true.

Comment: @jackblank I edited the answer to add links to the official pages with (sometimes scarce) documentation