# Resize facebook share button

Tags: css, html, facebook

I would like to resize the facebook share button. The default one provided by facebook is ridiculously small, and I am having difficulty resizing it. I tried overwriting the class, and even adding an ID, but nothing that has achieved desired result.

I mean below is the facebook share button:

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-layout="icon"></div>
```

any help would be greatly appreicated, and please note that it also has to look good on mobile, i just need more flexibility in customization.

Comment: What is the CSS applied by this class? And you should be able to just set height and width on it.

Comment: i simply use this .fb-share-button { width:100px; height: 100px; }

Comment: ... and where is the problem?

Comment: A frame that contains the real share button is added programatically, so just changing the style of the `div` will do nothing. You need to add styling for the `div` and `span` inside the frame. You may want to look at the generated code (inspect element) and play with the styles of `.pluginButton`, `.pluginButtonContainer`, `.pluginButtonImage`, and `.pluginButtonLabel`

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro: You can not format elements displayed inside that iframe from the “outer” document.

Comment: Only way to achieve this, is to apply `zoom` or a scale transformation to the element that the iframe gets rendered into – results will presumably look poorly though.

Comment: @CBroe, you are right. user3907211, if you really want to customize the button, I'd personally go with a picture and the share link instead of the API as I explain on this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510338/custom-image-for-facebook-share-button/28510392#28510392

Answer (score 1):

The Facebook Share button does not directly allow you to modify the style of the button. However you are able to create your own share button which will allow you to customize this to reflect the feel of your website.

For example for you can utilize the Javascript SDK to spawn a share dialog like so:

```
FB.ui({
   method: 'share',
   href: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/',
}, function(response){});
```

You can also use a URL redirect and link this with your custom button.

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/share?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&href=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fexplorer
```

Please reference the following documentation for further details on the implementation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

However please ensure you adhere to the Facebook Brand Guidelines outlined here https://www.facebookbrand.com/