# Customize the default Facebook Share button provided in developers.facebook.com

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, sdk, web-deployment, share-button

i have a custom image for facebook, that when the user click, it will share something, however, developers.facebook provide element that will automatically generate share button with the below code

```
<div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" data-layout="button"></div>
```

I want to use my custom image to use the code generated to popup the share page, is there a way?

```
%a.link.facebook{href: "some_url_here"}
```

I already search the net, still I'm stuck,

Thanks for your help , im still a beginner, :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom image for Facebook share button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28510338/custom-image-for-facebook-share-button)

Comment: Make your own button, and then use `FB.ui` out of the JS SDK, or open your own popup with the URL version of the Share dialog. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many suggestion are useful, thanks to all of them, but i find this method more simple, I want to share it to you guys.

Javascript (put it in header or footer)--

```
<script>
function fbShare(url, title, descr, image, winWidth, winHeight) {
    var winTop = (screen.height / 2) - (winHeight / 2);
    var winLeft = (screen.width / 2) - (winWidth / 2);
    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + title + '&p[summary]=' + descr + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + image, 'sharer', 'top=' + winTop + ',left=' + winLeft + ',toolbar=0,status=0,width=' + winWidth + ',height=' + winHeight);
}
</script>
```

to your link or image

```
<a href="javascript:fbShare('http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/EYxTJ/', 'Fb Share', 'Facebook share popup', 'http://goo.gl/dS52U', 520, 350)">Share</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/stichoza/eyxtj/